# Convert docker container ls -q output into a python list

Tags: python, docker, command-line

I'm trying to convert the command line return of `docker container ls -q` into a python list using the os.system library and method.

Is there a way to do this using the os library?

Essentially I'm trying to check if there are any running containers before I proceed through my code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The [Docker SDK for Python](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) would be a better match for this application.  (But remember that having access to the Docker socket at all implies unrestricted root-level access over the whole host; does your application _need_ this level of privilege?)

Comment: 1). Use `subprocess` rather than `os.system` and capture `stdout/stderr` using it, and 2). You have to do your own processing logic yourself. It's not that difficult. Or 3). Use an actual SDK or framework for Docker in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also found that `os.popen('docker container ls -q').read().split('\n')` works as well. Thank you for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Docker SDK for Python](https://pypi.org/project/docker/) using `pip install docker`.

Now you can use this code:

```
import docker

client = docker.from_env()
cn_list = client.containers.list()
print(cn_list)
```

The output you would get will be a list of Container objects lie this:
`[<Container: efda62a9af>, <Container: c5de5e6633>,...]`